# PyQt/PySide2 problem with QThread implementation where I'm trying to pass a method of another class to the thread class constructor

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qthread, pyside2

So, here I'm, a newbie who is trying to reinvent the wheel and also do the threading in a proper way in PySide2.
My problem is that my thread seems to start just fine, but I get no output from the function it is supposed to execute and I can't understand why.

Here is a brief explanation of how I've set it all up and a minimal reproducible example.
I have a file, let's say its called "so_helpers" for the purpose of my demonstration. Inside there are 2 classes, one is the QThread called "External" that I'm trying to construct and run in a smart way(obviously not, since it doesn't work) and the other one is Updater whose method I'm trying to pass to External to execute. Here is the code of my "so_helpers":

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, Signal

class Updater: 
    def __init__(self):
        print("connection to db established")

    def process(self):
        print("started")
        print("doing the update")
        print("finished")

class External(QThread):
    finished = Signal()

    def __init__(self, func):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func

    def run(self):
        self.func()
        self.finished.emit()
```

And this is my ui, for the purpose of this example let's call it "for_SO_ui". It was automatically generated by pyuic5 from the .ui file:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(644, 187)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(644, 187))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(644, 187))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 491, 111))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "THREADING IS AWESOME!"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the main.py where it all should come together(but it doesn't and that saddens me):

```
from so_helpers import *
from for_SO_ui import *
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, Signal
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    startThread = Signal()
    threadDone = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connectSignals()

    def connectSignals(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)
        self.startThread.connect(self.onThreadStart)
        self.threadDone.connect(self.onThreadDone)

    def onButtonClick(self):
        self.startThread.emit()

    def onThreadStart(self):
        self.thread_object = External(self.threadFunction)
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.thread_object.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread_object.finished.connect(self.onThreadDone)
        self.thread.start()

    def onThreadDone(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def threadFunction(self):
        func = Updater.process
        return func

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.thread.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any help, explanations, recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

First of all, `External` already is a QThread subclass, and there's no need to create a new thread to put it into. Even in that case, whenever you move a QObject to another thread, you should connect the `started` signal of the thread to the actual function that should be executed (in your case, `run`).

Calling `self.func()` will *not* run the `process` function, but the `threadFunction` instead, which just returns `Updater.process`.

Then, you want access to a function, but you're returning the unbound class method instead (`Updater.process`), not the instance method, so calling it would cause an exception, since `process` requires at least an argument (`self`).
You can use a `@staticmethod` (and remove `self`), or create an instance of the class.

Finally, QThread already has a `finished()` signal, you should not overwrite it, nor you should use your own signal to restart the thread: when you emit your own signal the thread would still be running, and the result is that it's possible that it won't be started again as explained in the documentation about [`QThread.start()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#start):

> [...] If the thread is already running, this function does nothing.

So you either use the original QThread `finished` signal, or you use [`QThread.wait()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#wait) to wait for completion before starting it again.

This is a possible correction for your code :

```
class External(QThread):
    def __init__(self, func):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func

    def run(self):
        self.func()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    startThread = pyqtSignal()
    threadDone = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connectSignals()

    def connectSignals(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)
        self.startThread.connect(self.onThreadStart)
        self.threadDone.connect(self.onThreadDone)

    def onButtonClick(self):
        self.startThread.emit()

    def onThreadStart(self):
        self.thread = External(self.threadFunction())
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.onThreadDone)
        self.thread.start()

    def onThreadDone(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def threadFunction(self):
        self.updater = Updater()
        return self.updater.process

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.thread.finished.disconnect(self.onThreadDone)
        self.thread.quit()
```

<sub>PS: For future reference: if docstrings/comments are not required for better comprehension of your code, remove them.</sub>

Comment: That explains so much. Thank you for taking the time to thoroughly explain how it should work and why. I hope that your answer will become a go to reference for people who are stuck with the same thing as I was.
PS: removed the unnecessary docstrings as per your suggestion.